# Does a $K_n$ with $n$ pendants have a name?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology

Consider the graph we get by taking the complete graph on $n$ vertices, and then attaching a pendant vertex to each of the $n$ vertices by an edge. Does such a graph have a name, i.e. do such graphs appear somewhere in the literature? Informally, this is like the star graph, but the center is not a single vertex, but a clique.

For example, such graphs are split graphs, but not every split graph is such a graph, so this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the corona of $K_n$ and $K_1$, usually denoted $K_n \circ K_1$.

The original definition was by Harary and Frucht in 1970 in their paper ["On the Corona of Two Graphs"](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/44326/10_2005_Article_BF01844162.pdf?sequence=1)

See this question for an application of it to more general graphs:
 [Eccentricity in corona product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460205/eccentricity-in-corona-product)